# How can I set a field to null in a Pre-Update Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I developed a Pre-Update Plugin for the Case entity. In this plugin I want to set a string field to a new value.
It works smoothly if the new value is not null. But if the new value si null, it is just ignored.

This works:

```
Incident caseTarget = ((Entity) localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"]).ToEntity<Incident>();
caseTarget.ProductSerialNumber = "new value";
```

After the execution of the plugin, the *ProductSerialNumber* field has value "new value".

This doesn't work:

```
Incident caseTarget = ((Entity) localContext.PluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"]).ToEntity<Incident>();
caseTarget.ProductSerialNumber = null;
```

After the execution of the plugin, the *ProductSerialNumber* field has still its old value.

How can I set the target's field to null?

Comment: For what it's worth, I tested this with a custom entity and setting any string field to `null` works, regardless of whether it's a property in the property bag or not. Out of curiosity, which classes does the `incident` class in the generated file inherit? Does it inherit `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging` or `System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged`?